# Go multidimensonal array variable assignment and usage for os/exec

Tags: go

I am trying to create an array of commands in golang and loop through them. I am not sure if I should use a map or a slice and I am sure my syntax is wrong. This is my first golang app and I am struggling from the docs. Can't find my use case.

The issue is assigning the variables. The syntax is incorrect and will not compile.

```
var c2[9][...]string{
            [3]string{"/c", "ipconfig", "/all"},
            [3]string("/c", "ipconfig", "/all"),
            [3]string("/c", "arp", "-a"),
            [3]string("/c", "route", "print"),
            [2]string("/c", "set"),
            [2]string("/c", "systeminfo"),
            [3]string("/c", "wmic", "qfe"),
            [3]string("/c", "tasklist", "/svc"),
            [3]string("/c", "query", "user"),
    }
    for i := range len(c2) { //assign
            x, e := exec.Command("cmd.exe", c2[i][0], c2[i][1], c2[i][2]).Output()
            if e != nil {
                    log.Fatal(e)
            }
            fmt.Println(string(x))
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using fixed-length arrays, use slices:

```
var c2 = [][]string{
        {"/c", "ipconfig", "/all"},
        {"/c", "ipconfig", "/all"},
        {"/c", "arp", "-a"},
        {"/c", "route", "print"},
        {"/c", "set"},
        {"/c", "systeminfo"},
        {"/c", "wmic", "qfe"},
        {"/c", "tasklist", "/svc"},
        {"/c", "query", "user"},
    }
```

Then, run your commands:

```
for i := range len(c2) { //assign
      x, e := exec.Command("cmd.exe", c2[i]...).Output()
            if e != nil {
                    log.Fatal(e)
            }
            fmt.Println(string(x))
    }
```